# How to convert extracted python request URL variable to string?

Tags: python, python-requests, bottle

I am new to python web applications. I am using Bottlepy for my web application and request for extracting variables from URLs. I extracted the variable `first=request.query.first`. I can return the value of the variable but when I want to use it in if condition it always fails and else block is executed.

URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/h?first="hi"`

```
@app.route('/h')
def test():
    first=request.query.first
    if first == "hi":
        return "passed"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

I will appreciate your help regarding the problem thank you.

Comment: Hint: Before your `if` statement, simply print out the value of `first`.

Comment: Before if statement the print result is  "hi"  but still the if condition fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the URL many times then I noticed that I was putting quotation marks around `"hi"` removing the quotation fixed the problem. The new URL is `http://localhost:8080/h?first=hi`.

Answer (score 0):

this should effectively convert the URL variable to string.
after you do `first=request.query.first`

```
newfirst=str(first)
```

then in the test function change first to newfirst

```
def test():
    if newfirst == "hi":
        return "passed"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still fails.